# Embedding dynamic variable in ngFor in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, variables, formatting, ngfor

I'm getting a syntax error when I write this code...

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let incident of incidents | paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, currentPage: page }">
    <td>{{ incident.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.str }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.mtdna }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.ystr }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.xstr }}</td>
    <td>{{ incident.snps }}</td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" (click)="editRecord({{incident.id}})" class="btn btn-primary float-start">
      Edit {{ incident.id }}
      </button>
    </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The issue is the `(click)="editRecord({{incident.id}})"` part of this code.

Angular 11 is not allowing me to embed the id into the editRecord() method call.

If I write `(click)="editRecord(1)`, then the error goes away.

My question is, how do I embed the id into the editRecord method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for {{ }}, you can just avoid that becase (click)="`expects variable or method calls or executable code`"

```
<button type="submit" (click)="editRecord(incident.id)" class="btn btn-primary float-start">
      Edit {{ incident.id }}
      </button>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks Vaira!